# installing ubuntu 14.04 theme from zip file?

Tags: 14.04, themes, unity-tweak-tool

I'm using 14.04LTS and I have downloaded this theme : https://github.com/baurigae/polar-day ,
and tried to install it by extracting the folder to user/share/themes and then I looked at unity tweak tool and I didn't find it! could someone please tell me what to do ??.

Comment: There are no installation instructions included. If copying to /usr/share/themes doesn't work, you should contact the developer, and ask.

Answer (score 1):

It works well enough here. Perhaps try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install git
mkdir $HOME/.themes && cd $HOME/.themes
git clone https://github.com/baurigae/polar-day --depth 1
```

Then the tweak tool should be able to find 'Polar-day' in its listing. Below is a screenshot showing this on my own Trusty Tahr installation:

[image]

It is a bit of a pain that the theme is only released on git but easy enough anyway to get a copy...